# CakePHP not working, showing PHP Code inline PHP

Tags: cakephp, amazon-web-services, bitnami

**Edit:** I know what is causing the problem now, but still no solution. Basically unless the `tmp` directory is 777 Cake is unable to write to it so it fails. And if `tmp` is 777 then because of maybe some weird security setting PHP doesn't work. Any ideas if this is a possibility and how I can fix it?

**Edit 2:** Is it possible that because of character encoding the tmp is not 777 its showing `?` garbage characters.

I just migrated my CakePHP app to Amazon AWS (Using a BitNami LAMPstack). I was getting PHP errors saying Could Not Connect to DB (which means PHP is executing).

When I fixed the DB settings it is now printing inline PHP.
For example:

```
<title><?php echo $title_for_layout; ?></title>
```

is showing in the HTML and the document title is hence a snippet of PHP code!

Please help I'm at a loss. Things I've tried doing:

- Changing AllowOverride to All in the  section in/opt/bitnami/apache2/conf/httpd.conf
- Editing my php.ini for short_open_tag=On just in case
- Making sure mod_rewrite is enabled in httpd.conf and that my `htdocs` and `app` folder have the correct `.htaccess` files.

Here are my .htaccess files just in case:

`htdocs/.htaccess`

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
       RewriteEngine on
       RewriteRule    ^$ app/webroot/    [L]
       RewriteRule    (.*) app/webroot/$1 [L]
</IfModule>

Options All -Indexes
```

`htdocs/app/.htaccess`

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine on
    RewriteRule    ^$    webroot/    [L]
    RewriteRule    (.*) webroot/$1    [L]
</IfModule>
```

`htdocs/app/webroot/.htaccess`

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?/$1 [QSA,L]
</IfModule>
```

Comment: Have you changed anything in default htaccess file?

Comment: No, but checking them again and reuploading.

Comment: They seem fine :( Adding them to question just in case.

Comment: There is some problem in php.ini file. Restore it and check. This link also might help you. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5121495/php-code-is-not-being-executed-i-can-see-it-on-source-code-of-page

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well all I can say is thank god I paid attention in class last semester when they explained character encoding.

So I opened up all the .ctp files that weren't being exec'd as PHP in `vim`. I said `:set encoding=utf-8` and `:set fileencoding=utf-8`
and then `:x` (keeping it newb-friendly just in case somebody wants a quick fix) :)

And its working like it should now. :)